# How show <a> after <span> after <b> tag data in my listbox1?

Tags: regex, split

How show all b tag data in the list box area if below position available?

```
<pre>
 <a class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav" href="/SectionSyndica" data-user-id="2461389152">
    <img class="avatar js-action-profile-avatar" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/459312647012229120/pYPrhPl2_bigger.jpeg" alt="">
    <strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id" data-aria-label-part="">Section Syndicale</strong>
    <span>‏</span><span class="username js-action-profile-name" data-aria-label-part=""><s>@</s><b>SectionSyndica</b></span>

  </a>

</pre>
<pre>
 <a class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav" href="/SectionSyndica" data-user-id="2461389152">
    <img class="avatar js-action-profile-avatar" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/459312647012229120/pYPrhPl2_bigger.jpeg" alt="">
    <strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id" data-aria-label-part="">olikyekso dieo</strong>
    <span>‏</span><span class="username js-action-profile-name" data-aria-label-part=""><s>@</s><b>olikyeksodkd</b></span>

  </a>

</pre>
```

Result show below process in my listbox

sectionsyndica

olikyeksodkd

This code not working what I am try for working!!!

```
HtmlElementCollection bdColld = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
foreach (HtmlElement bdEld in bdColld)
{
if (bdEld.GetAttribute("b") != null)
listBox1.Items.Add(bdEld.GetAttribute("b"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use regex, u can use the pattern below

```
/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g
```

Comment: i don't know how c# captures regex groups. But this may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx. If u want i can provide u php code.